# No Activity or Krausen

Tags: fermentation, primary-fermentation, wyeast

Something that has never happened to me.  Brewed early Sunday and hit 80+% efficiency.  I used Wyeast London Ale that was fully bloated when pitched.  Over 36 hours later zero activity.  No krausen, No air lock movement...nada.

It is a heavier beer (1.080) and I did not have time for a starter so it is possible that the yeast is working but not enough to show anything visable.  I am going to check the gravity when I get home, but in case nothing changed what is the best course of action?

Should I buy another Wyeast pack?  Dry yeast?  etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of several questions about slow starts to fermentation. Some of them focus on temperature, and some suggest using more yeast because of high gravity.

Comment: I figured the answer was on here, I just couldn't find anything.  I appreciate the response.